# Update horizontal link list with jQuery Mobile and Knockout JS

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm using jQuery mobile and Knockout JS (latest versions of both).

I cannot seem to style a horizontal list after knockout updates the dom.

```
<h2>Dynamic</h2>
<div id="dynamicControlgroup" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"  data-mini="true" data-bind="foreach: Labels">

<a href="#" data-role="button" data-bind="text: Label"></a>

</div>
<h2>Static</h2>
<div id="staticControlgroup" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
    <a href="#" data-role="button">3G</a>
 <a href="#" data-role="button">SD</a>
<a href="#" data-role="button">HD</a>
<a href="#" data-role="button">HD+</a>
/div>
```

The "Static" looks good, but the "dynamic" is not styled by jQuery mobile. I've tried several methods of trying to make this work, and I am missing something... after knockout runs, I do:

```
$("#dynamicControlgroup").trigger("create")
$("#dynamicControlgroup").children('a').buttonMarkup({ inline: true,mini: true,corners: true, type: "horizontal"});
```

But here is what it looks like:

[image: button exampe]

Thoughts?

Comment: What does the initialized HTML look like for the dynamic versus static control groups? There will be some discrepancies, I'd look there first.

Comment: There's code mistake or is it a typos? `/div>`.

Answer (score 1):

After appending new items, use the below code.

```
$('[data-role="controlgroup"]').controlgroup().trigger('create');
```

> **Note:** Creating completely new `controlgroup` doesn't get enhanced corners dynamically. However, appending new items into existing `controlgroup` corners get enhanced. This problem can be solved by adding `ui-first-child` and `ui-last-child` classes.

```
$('[data-role="controlgroup"] a').first().addClass('ui-first-child');

$('[data-role="controlgroup"] a').last().addClass('ui-last-child');
```

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/Cf5yH/)**

Comment: I think we are close, but Knockout removes the bindings of the button. Doing your suggestion results in <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls"></div></div> with the <a>tags not nested inside...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out with Knockout you need to remove the controlgroup from the div so you dont get the "empty wrapper". So the dynamic code looks like:

```
<h2>Dynamic</h2>
<div id="dynamicControlgroup" data-type="horizontal"  data-mini="true"     data-bind="foreach: Labels">

<a href="#" data-role="button" data-bind="text: Label"></a>

</div>
```

and then on page load, you can call

```
$('#dynamicControlgroup').controlgroup().trigger('create');
$('#dynamicControlgroup a').first().addClass('ui-first-child');
$('#dynamicControlgroup a').last().addClass('ui-last-child');
```

and this works. Thanks to Omar for the help on the first/last rounded classes tip!